# Ruby .map hash values to key value pair in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
a = {one: 2, two: 3}.map{|k,v| {k => v}}  # => [{:one=>2}, {:two=>3}]

a[0]        # => {:one=>2}
a[0].class  # => Hash
a[0].key    # ~> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

Expected output:

```
[{one: 2}, {two: 3}]
```

which would result in a[0].key >> :one

Why can't I get the key value of the 1st item in the array?

Solution: keys.first.

Comment: You've mixed up `:one` and `"one"`. You should write the last line `a[0].key => :one` or `a[0].key #=> :one`.

Comment: I did not understand a word from the statements above, but they surely do not contain a question, so downvoted.

Comment: `[{one: 2}, {two: 3}]` is identical in value (just written using alternate syntax) to `[{:one=>2}, {:two=>3}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Checking [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-key), `hash#key` requires an argument which is the value you'd like to locate a corresponding key for:

```
p a[0].key(2) # => :one
```

The search is linear, using `rb_hash_foreach` to iterate over the pairs in the hash.

Comment: The OP may be looking for `a[0].keys.first #=> :one`. (We can't tell from the question.)